# How to pass locale to ActiveJob / SuckerPunch when sending delayed email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob, sucker-punch

In my Rails 5 app I am trying to send emails with [ActiveJob](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) and [Sucker Punch](https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch):

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def activate
    user = User.find_by(:activation_token => params[:id])
    user.activate
    SendFollowUpEmailJob.perform_in(30, user)
    sign_in user
  end

end
```

---

```
# app/jobs/send_follow_up_email.rb

class SendFollowUpEmailJob < ActiveJob::Base
  include SuckerPunch::Job

  queue_as :default

  def perform(user)
    SupportMailer.follow_up(user).deliver_later
  end
end
```

---

```
# app/mailers/support_mailer.rb

class SupportMailer < ApplicationMailer

  layout nil

  default :from => "admin@app.com"

  def follow_up(user)
    @user = user
    mail :to => @user.email, :subject => t('.subject')
  end

end
```

---

```
# app/views/user_mailer/activation.html.erb

<%= link_to(t('views.activate'), activate_user_url(@user.activation_token, :locale => "#{I18n.locale}")) %>
```

---

Everything works except that the email is always sent in the default locale rather than the locale that was passed into the `activate` action.

All emails throughout the application are always sent in the correct locale, so it must down to either **ActiveJob** or **SuckerPunch**.

If you can help, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: How do you set the locale?

Comment: @VasiliyErmolovich: Just added the email view template above. The locale gets passed in through the URL which works perfectly for all other mailers. I wonder why it fails here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm familiar with I18n within the application, but not so much in mailers. Remember that the mailer is being sent outside the request (ActiveJob), so it has no knowledge of anything that happened there. It looks like you haven't done anything to tell the mailer that it should be sending in a specific locale....

OK maybe this has the answer for you (and me!) https://niallburkley.com/blog/localize-rails-emails/

```
I18n.with_locale(@user.locale) do
  mail(
    to: @user.email,
    subject: I18n.t('user_mailer.new_follower.subject')
  )
end
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right, the locale has to be passed in manually.